# WPF TextBoxBase (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives) get text

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I get the `.Text` from a WPF (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives) TextBoxBase. Here is the code:

```
    private TextBoxBase mTextBox;
    this.mTextBox.Text;
```

The WPF Controls does not contain a definitions for `.Text` I also tried using a TextRange but that did not work. Here is the code:

```
    string other = new TextRange(((RichTextBox)sender).Document.ContentStart, ((RichTextBox)sender).Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

How can I get the `.Text` from my WPF (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives) TextBoxBase?

Comment: for more check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754041(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No that is for a RichTextBox I need the code for a TextBoxBase

Comment: Why would you need the code for a `TextBoxBase` if you are using a `RichTextBox`? The `Text` property only exists in the `TextBox` class. `TextBoxBase` is the base class of both controls but it does not contains such a property. `TextBoxBase` is an abstract class anyway so you cannot instantiate it.  Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I believe the `RichTextBox` is the sender but I am using a `TextBoxBase`. A `TextBoxBase` if for a `RichTextBox`?

Comment: How can you be using a `TextBoxBase` since it is an abstract type? Your object should have a more concrete type : either `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`(or more derived types), otherwise this is not possible. Show us the XAML document as well.

Comment: There are 2 implementations (at least) for `TextBoxBase`, so using type checking, figure that out, then grab the `.Text` value accordingly. HTH...

Answer (score 3):

There are not any Text property in the WPF `RichTextBox` control. Below is a way to get all texts:

```
string GetString(RichTextBox rtb)
 {
   var textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
   return textRange.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you question stays at

> How can I get the .Text from my WPF (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives) [`TextBoxBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Then the short answer is: you can't since there is no such property.

Now the only known controls that directly inherit from [`TextBoxBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are [`TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [`TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) DOES have a [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, but [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) DOESN'T.

If you are using TextBox, you can cast your object and then get the property:

```
var textBox = mTextBox as TextBox;
if (textBox != null)
{
    var text = textBox.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an extension method like this?

```
public static string GetTextValue(this TextBoxBase source)
{
    // need to cast TextBoxBase to one of its implementations
    var txtControl = source as TextBox;
    if (txtControl == null)
    {
        var txtControlRich = source as RichTextBox;
        if (txtControlRich == null) return null;
        return txtControlRich.Text;
    }

    return txtControl.Text;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but hopefully you get the general idea.